# How to install rpm tool on Mac OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, homebrew

How to install rpm tool on OS X?

Brew doesn't have it yet and the binaries I found so far are too old (not intel 64bit).

Comment: What packages do you need rpm for?

Comment: I need RPM just to be able to get some information out of RPM files, not for installing stuff.

Comment: `brew install rpm2cpio` now works [then you have the rpm2cpio.pl command available to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended-up installing macports and using it to install rpm (`port install rpm`)

It took about an hour to compile all the dependencies, even if I do have 4 cores and a SSD.

Comment: Mac ports now provides binary downloads (albeit the Yosemite server has not competed the compiles yet)

Answer (score 4):

brew install rpm will work. It downloads all the dependencies; though it takes lot of time to compile the packages

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using something like VirtualBox and installing an rpm-based OS, assuming you're just looking to use things like `rpmbuild`.  CentOS works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Check into getting [`rpm2cpio`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm2cpio) and [`cpio`](http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/html_mono/cpio.html) programs as noted in [How to extract RPM package without installing it](http://www.geekride.com/how-to-extract-rpm-package-without-installing-it/)

> **Extract RPM file:**
>
> To extract an RPM file there is no option available in RPM command. But there is a small utility availble called rpm2cpio and cpio. This utility extracts the cpio archive from RPM. rpm2cpio converts the .rpm file specified as a single argument to a cpio archive on standard out.

Both are available in [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), as noted in [this cpio search](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=cpio). Additionally you could build both the programs from source manually as noted from there respective sources if you can't find a working solution on MacPorts or homebrew:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/cpio.html
- http://rpm5.org/